# How to change button label from "Save" to "Open" in Flash's FileReference.browse dialog

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

In AS3, the `FileReference.browse()` function always has a "Save" button label. In fact, the dialog's title seems to be "Select a file to upload..." and then the button label says "Save", which is completely weird.

Is there a way to change the button label from `Save` to `Open` or something?

Same goes for the "Save as format" drop-down at the bottom. If the dialog is used to open a file this is very misleading. Is this a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From this doc, it seems that you can't http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse%28%29

This seems to be possible only in Adobe AIR:

> Note: The File class, available in Adobe AIR, includes methods for accessing more specific system file selection dialog boxes. These methods are File.browseForDirectory(), File.browseForOpen(), File.browseForOpenMultiple(), and File.browseForSave().

Comment: this definitely seems like a bug to me. the same dialog saying "upload" and "save" is just wrong.

Comment: just for info, did you checked if `FileReferenceList.browse()` (which allows multiple selection) behaves different?

Comment: Yes, seems like a bug, the button says "Save" on Windows but "Open" on the Mac, when I test the same swf, the same code, the AS docs example code.